# on dart: cast string to double fails

Tags: c, flutter, dart

I have socket listen on Dart, that receives messages from server (written on C).

Client (Dart):

```
(Uint8List data) async {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    String serverResponse = String.fromCharCodes(data);
      globals.progressEvent = double.parse(serverResponse));
  }
```

Server(C):

```
send(client_fd, "90", BUFFER_LENGTH, 0);
```

When run it, I see an exception "**Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid double**"

it fails on line "**double.parse(serverResponse))**"

What can be the reason?

Comment: Because `serverResponse` does not contain a valid representation of a floating point number? Did you check that?

Answer (score 0):

### Check String parser

As the commenter suggested, I'd recommend checking whether the String you get in Dart corresponds to what the server sends. Have you tried printing it to take a look?

Additionally, I'd generally advise you to use `double.tryparse`, which will not throw an exception, but instead return `null` when parsing fails. You can then see if it's null, and if so print some debugging information.

### Encoding

I'm not too familiar with how Dart handles binary data, but to me it looks like you use 1 byte for each character (UTF-8), whereas Dart's `fromCharCodes` seems to conventionally use the UTF-16 format, with 2 bytes per character. When trying to parse your 9 and 0 together, I guess it gets a non-numeric value, causing the parser to faill. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/String.fromCharCodes.html